# link_to ruby rails modal bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, link-to

I'm building my index html page and I'd like to have for each of my elements (in this case, restaurants) one modal appearing with more restaurant details.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="container text-centered">
  <h1>Welcome to La Cuillère</h1>
   <h2>Restaurants you can go to</h2>

 <ul>
   <% @restaurants.each do |r| %>
     <li>
       <%= link_to r.name, {"data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#restaurant_modal_#{r.id}"} %>
       <%= render "restaurant_modal", restaurant: r %>
     </li>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
  <%= link_to 'Add a new restaurant', new_restaurant_path, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
</div>
```

And then there is a partial (restaurant_modal.htlm.erb) with the code of my modal inside:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="restaurant_modal_<%= restaurant.id %>">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Could you please help me and tell me what's wrong in this code.

Comment: And what the problem is exactly? BTW showing details in modal is a terrible design flaw.

Comment: The modal doesn't appear on the screen, and sorry for the design flaw, i'm in a learning process.

Comment: "http://localhost:8000/restaurants?data-target=%23restaurant_modal_1&data-toggle=modal"

the URL i got when I click on one restaurant link

Comment: Does the modal show up if in developer console (shift + ctrl + i / cmd + ctrl + i) you run `$('restaurant_modal_ID').modal('open')`?

Answer (score 0):

```ruby
<%= link_to r.name, "#", "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#restaurant_modal_#{r.id}" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately not working :( I'm wondering what i've missed...

Comment: I think the link should rather lead to restaurant path.

Answer (score -1):

the link must not have href. Try using remote: true or remove the link href.

Read this for remote option: [Javascript with rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to)